# How do you draw a slash animation on an android phone?

Tags: android, animation

I would like to draw a slash animation between 2 points that I have already randomly generated.

The animation can be as simple as the line extending to the other point over a set amount of time. I would like the animation to be a "pretty" line so I was using a bunch of images and iterating over them and not just canvas.drawLine(x, y, u, v, paint).

The main issue I am running into is the points are not always the same distance apart or same direction. Im not sure if having a set number of animation sequences would work because of those differences. What is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this has been answered, but you'll have to say how complicated your imagery is. If it's a simple slash line, then drawLine would work. You'll also have to say how you are animating the line, like Android XML or if you are using some sort of timer.

There's so many ways to do this. If it's a simple line, you can use math to increment some coordinates. Watch out for using frame counting, where you say "increment the animation for the frame". It's a quick-and-dirty way to animate, and sometimes will get the job done.

A lot of video games use time-based drawing. "If this amount of time has elapsed since the last draw, draw this much". The result looks much more natural and the same between devices with different amount of horsepower.

There's also what you are drawing on. Are you using a View or a SurfaceView? The list goes on.